# Ember.js Routing and Connecting Outlets

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I am trying to set up an Ember router application, but I am unable to use the connectOulet method of the Controller object to connect views to specific outlets(outlets with names, ie: `{{outlet outletName}}`). I have set up a JSFiddle example, can someone tell me what I am doing wrong or how to actually go about doing this?

The JSFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/TmKwd/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hum, I can't exactly explain why, but the ApplicationController must not be defined as an Ember.ObjectController, but only an Ember.Controller instead.

**UPDATE**

After a quick debug, this is when calling connectOutlet on the applicationController, especially the line `set(this, outletName, view);`
As `outletName` (in your example, this is "one" and "two") is an unknown property in the applicationController, and since you define the applicationController as an ObjectController (so a proxy wrapping the content property), Ember.js tries to set the view on the content, which is undefined/null.

As a result, this error is thrown:

`Uncaught Error: assertion failed: Cannot delegate set('one', <App.ViewOneView:ember208>) to the 'content' property of object proxy <App.ApplicationController:ember209>: its 'content' is undefined.`